# NetLogo: Issue with Chooser

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to do a disease simulation where you can choose which disease to simulate. To achieve this, I've added a chooser to the Interface, which is named "disease", with options like smallpox, measles and mumps. It is also accompanied by the following code in the setup:

```
if disease = smallpox
[
set infection-rate 90
set infectivity 6
set lethality 30
set recovery recovery-rate
set immunity (1 - (1 / infectivity)) * 100
]

if disease = measles
[
  set infection-rate 90
  set infectivity 15
  set lethality 1
  set recovery recovery-rate
  set immunity (1 - (1 / infectivity)) * 100
]

if disease = mumps
[
  set infection-rate 80
  set infectivity 6
  set lethality 1
  set recovery recovery-rate
  set immunity (1 - (1 / infectivity)) * 100
]
```

And the following:

```
ask turtles with [sick? != true and immune? != true]
[if any? (turtles-on patch-ahead 1) with [sick? = true]
[if (random 100) < infection-rate
  [
    set sick? true
  ]

]
]
```

In the Interface, I've also set up a tracker to track the "infection-rate". However, when I run the program, the infection-rate sits at zero; furthermore, the turtles aren't infecting others. (This isn't an issue, as I've tried my "infection" code with manually set values and it worked.)

Is there something wrong with how I'm coding the "ifs", or rather how I'm trying to work with the variables? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try with quotes around the string that indicates the disease- eg `if disease = "mumps"`

Comment: Could you provide more code? @LukeC I think you're right about the strings, but need to confirm that he doesn't have a global variable called mumps.

Comment: One way to help debug, is to put print statements around the code in question. For example, where do you set infection-rate; put a print statement after it to see if it's being set correctly.

Comment: That's fair @mattsap, but my thinking is that unless the global variable `mumps` is assigned the string "mumps" the conditional statement would not evaluate as true when the chooser is set to "mumps". If the user *also* has a global called mumps, that might be confusing but should not conflict as far as I understand it. If I'm misunderstanding please let me know!

Comment: @LukeC Was right, quotes fixed it. NetLogo truly perplexes me to this day.

Comment: It is a fickle beast! If you're curious, this works because the chooser ("disease" in this case) is a global variable. When you choose one the options, you set the global variable to that option. If it weren't a string, you'd be trying to say "set the disease global variable to the mumps global variable" (which you can't actually do- the "Chooser" setup only allows for string values and numbers as possible choices)